# DOM innerHTML does not accept my html data

Tags: javascript, dom

```
    var popupcontent = myfunc(item.Id, i);
    tablepopup = document.createElement("table");
    tablepopup.innerHTML = popupcontent;
    highSlide.appendChild(tablepopup);
    tdAnkunft.appendChild(kirmiziOkLink);
    tdAnkunft.appendChild(highSlide);
    tableRow.appendChild(tdAnkunft);
```

Hi, 
myfunc returns an html table code like "table../table" but i am getting an error :"htmlfile: Unknown runtime error" 
is there any alternative way to parse my string data "popupcontent" into tablepopup ?

a sample html code returns from myfunc is

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="table_header" style="cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#EEEEEE';"
        onmouseout="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF';">
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            Flug.
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            Flug Nr.
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            Flughafen Abflug
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            Datum
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            Abflug
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            Ankunft
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            C
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            S
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E4E4E4">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>







    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#EEEEEE';" onmouseout="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF';"
        style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="table_content" align="center">
            TK
        </td>
        <td class="table_content">
            351
        </td>
        <td class="table_content">
            Bremen - Frankfurt
        </td>
        <td class="table_content">
            13.05.2010
        </td>
        <td class="table_content" align="center">
            19:50
        </td>
        <td class="table_content" align="center">
            20:50
        </td>
        <td class="table_content" align="center">
            V
        </td>
        <td class="table_content" align="center">
            9
        </td>
        <td class="table_content" align="center">
            <img src="images/right.arrow.png" width="18" height="18" onclick="swapPlans('Bremen','349');">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: htmlfile: Unknown runtime error

Comment: perhaps you need to add the tablepopup into the document element using  appendChild()...

Comment: I am doing appendChild() later on. This is just a part of the script

Comment: It would help if we could see the `myfunc` script.

Comment: i sent the output coming from myfunc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
tablepopup.appendChild(document.createTextNode(popupcontent));
```

as an alternative.

From the code provided, it looks like your DOM tree is:

```
<tr>
    <td id="tdAnkunft">
        <unknown id="kirmiziOkLink">
        <table id="tablepopup">
            popupcontent
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Maybe make sure `popupcontent` returns a valid `<tr><td></td</tr>` tree.

If `myfunc` `return`s exactly the code you have provided in your original [edited] post then it would seem your DOM tree is invalid, as `<table id=tablepopup">` contains invalid code. Your DOM tree would look like:

```
<table id="popuptable">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Flug.
            </td>
            <td>
                Flug Nr.
            </td>
            <td>
                Flughafen Abflug.
            </td>
...
...
            <td>
                9.
            </td>
            <td>
                <img />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</table>
```

Notice you have a `table` within a `table` which is invalid HTML. This may well be your problem.

Comment: :) kirmiziOkLink is another D.O. which is being added before the table. Actually what I am doing is to use http://highslide.com/#examples this thing, but add them dynamically. I have many links which has class of kirmiziOkLink and the content which is my table. I hope i was clear!

Comment: Post, please, your desired DOM tree and the `return` of `myfunc` so we can debug your code.

Comment: i did, i edited the question. I want the same as the output which is the table I posted above !!

Comment: ok I fixed it, I was trying to append a string < table >... into a table object which should be starting with < tr ...
thanks all

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML expects a string with the new html of the element. `myfunc()` is probably returning something that cannot be parsed as html. Try passing something like `tablepopup.innerHTML = "<em>hi!</em>";` Could you post myfunc?

Also, what do you mean by "valid html table code"? If you are expecting `..` to back out one level of a directory its not going to work like that. You aren't specifying the location of an html file on the machine, but the actual html in string form. If you want to include html from a file url, you need a server-side language like PHP.

Comment: i am expecting <.table> .. <./table>
string is valid and generated dynamically. is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: post `myfunc`. there's probably something with your dynamic generation :D